# ng-repeat inside directive template won't update during test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a unit test for an angular directive. This directive has a `ng-repeat` inside its template which is bound to an array inside the directive's controller. The array changes when a method in the controller is called (this method actually gets called by a sub-directive, something like `addMe()`).
This works fine in 'real-life', but does not inside a Jasmine unit test. I can see in the debugger, that everything is called and the array has the correct contents, but somehow the `ng-repeat` won't update. I even tried to call `$scope.$digest()` inside the controller after a change to the array, but that doesn't work either.
Any help?
Daniel

Relevant part of the template is:

```
    <div class="step-wizard-header">
        <div class="step" 
            ng-repeat="title in titles" 
            ng-click="selectPage($index, 0)" 
            ng-class="{ active: currentIndex == $index, done: currentIndex > $index }">
            <span class="number">
                {{$index + 1}}
            </span>
            <span class="title">
                {{title.text}}
            </span>
            <div class="substep-holder" 
                ng-show="currentIndex == $index">
                <div class="substep" 
                    ng-repeat="sub in title.subs" 
                    ng-click="selectPage($parent.$index, $index); $event.stopPropagation()" 
                    ng-class="{ active: currentSubIndex == $index, done: currentSubIndex > $index      }">
                    {{sub.text}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-arrow" 
                ng-style="{ 'z-index': (titles.length - $index) }">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you share some html witth us at least? it's possible that u have an attribute in the tag that doesn't work with ng-repeat

Comment: Like I said, it works fine, except from inside a unit test.

Comment: ok. . .sorry I haven't done any active tdd, or developed any tests since 2010

Comment: We may need your test code to help you ;)

Comment: Instead of sharing my own code I would like to point to [this](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/testing-directives.html), which does exactly what I want, but doesn't work in my environment as well. Maybe I have a general issue in my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by some incompatibility due to the version of `ng-animate`. Updating everything (to 1.2.13 at the moment) solved the issue.

Comment: Please answer your own question to mark it as resolved